# Stick footer to the bottom of page

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I have tried all I can... Maybe you will help me.
According to Sticky footer and other things like that my container should be 100% height and footer always at bottom of the page, but I get nothing... Thanks

Mine site - http://mangobooking.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per your code: and a [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/3LyrD/) for you to see it

```
.footer {
    width: 1000px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -4px 5px 0px rgba(50,50,50,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -4px 5px 0px rgba(50,50,50,0.1);
     box-shadow: 0px -4px 5px 0px rgba(50,50,50,0.1);
   -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

AND, if you don't want it sticky (always stuck to the bottom) , i.e.-you have a page with more content and you just want it at the end of the page, simply change position to absolute